# IIS DNS Lookup for "XYZ" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException This host is unknown

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, iis-7.5

I have strange issue with IIS on my local machine.
IIS can't resolve host that bind to some specific name to 80 port.
I have  web site that bind to XYZ name and 80 port nothing special,
this XYZ name is present in host file as well.
it is no any information in IIS log, but if open web site with fiddler I see an error

*[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "XYZ" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException  host is unknown*

without fidler just next message

*This webpage is not available
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED*

default web site with localhost name iis can open easily.

What is the general issue with it ?

Comment: Are you able to access the site using localhost?

Comment: I have found solution https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2823477 I just wonder why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2823477 just install and be happy with this SP